# How to set empty column background color in List in swiftUI?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

I find that .listRowBackground(Color.Red.Blush) can set the list row column, but in the List there are some empty row are still white. When I scroll on the List, it also show some white area. Can somebody help to slove this peoblem? It's also appreciated for telling me how to change the color with the SegmentedPickerStyle. This video shows my problem. https://youtu.be/aEPw5hHBkFE
Thank you!

```
struct UserNotificationCellView: View {
@ObservedObject var userNotification: UserNotification
@ObservedObject var userNotifications: UserNotifications
    var body: some View {
       {
             ......          
        }
        .padding(.horizontal,20)
            .cornerRadius(14)
            .listRowBackground(Color.Red.Blush)
//          .background(Color.Red.Blush)
  }
}
```

Below is my List code

```
List {
            ForEach(userNotifications1.userNotificationsArray, id: \.notifyId) { (userNotification) in
                UserNotificationCellView(userNotification: userNotification,userNotifications: self.userNotifications1)
 //                        .listRowBackground(Color.Red.Blush)

            }.colorMultiply(Color.Red.Blush)
            Spacer()
        }.environment(\.defaultMinListRowHeight, 80)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend adding a global style in your AppDelegate class. From here you can change class properties that are currently inaccessible by SwiftUI via appearance.

```
UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear
UISegmentedControl.appearance().....
```

From here you can change your list background color and any segmented control properties you need to.

For the empty cells you can try adding an empty footer

```
List {
    Section(footer: self.footer) {
        ForEach(userNotifications1.userNotificationsArray, id: \.notifyId) { (userNotification) in
                UserNotificationCellView(userNotification: userNotification,userNotifications: self.userNotifications1)
 //                        .listRowBackground(Color.Red.Blush)

            }.colorMultiply(Color.Red.Blush)
        }
    }.environment(\.defaultMinListRowHeight, 80)
```